# Can I use application cache fallback for different hosts?

Tags: html, offline, fallback, application-cache

I have sample site:

```
/index.html
/appcache.manifest
/style.css
/test.js
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="appcache.manifest">
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script>window.google && window.google.maps || console.info('Fail');</script>
</body>
</html>
```

appcache.manifest:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

NETWORK:
*

CACHE:
index.html
style.css
test.js

FALLBACK:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false test.js
```

test.js:

```
window.google = window.google || {};
google.maps = google.maps || {};
console.info('I am work!!!')
```

When I open site first time on localhost without internet connection I see 'Fial' in console.

Can I use http://different_domain in application cache manifest fallback section and if I can what I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, [from the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html#concept-appcache-manifest-fallback):

> Fallback namespaces and fallback entries must have the same origin as
>   the manifest itself.

Comment: Is it allowed if one is absolute and one is relative (relatively evaluated to the same absolute URL)?

Comment: @Pacerier I'm not sure, what happens when you try it?

Comment: @Pacerier I'm not sure what that means?

Comment: @Pacerier I know what an RFC is, I'm asking what RFC are you referring to.

Comment: *any* RFC​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @Pacerier There are no RFCs that cover the HTML5 AppCache.  The standard which covers HTML5 AppCache is linked to from my answer above.